# Let R be a finite commutative ring with 1.Let a,b∈ R such that (a)+(b)=R and M be any maximal ideal of R with b∉M. Then is some x∈ R such that a+xb∉M

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with $1$.Let $a , b\in$ $R$ such that ($a$)+($b$)=$R$ and $M$ be any maximal ideal of $R$ with $b\not\in M$.Then I have to prove that there is some $x\in$ $R$ such that $a+xb\not\in$$M$

This is a part of a problem,may be not all the conditions will be needed.I have been trying it for last few days but I am not getting it anyway.Please help.Thank you.

Comment: So if you have been working on it for a few days, you should have some thoughts, or failed attempts. Why don't you tell us what you know and where you are stuck?

Comment: @ rogerl see sometimes it is not possible to show what you have tried.I tried using coprimeness of the ideals M and (b), also used that (a) and (b) are coprime, finiteness of R.But I am still missing the right point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need $(a)+(b)=R$ and we don't need that $R$ is finite.

Since the question is really only about membership in $M$ (or not in $M$), we may as well consider $R/M$, which is a field. The question becomes:

> If $F$ is a field with elements $a,b$ such that $b \neq 0$, then there is some $x \in F$ such that $a+xb \neq 0$.

But this is trivial, just $x=\frac{1-a}{b}$, then $a+xb=1$.

Comment: I cannot understand how a+xb does not belong to M.It is clear that b+M is a unit in the field R/M so it is not a zero divisor,how you connect b with a please explain it.

Comment: Forget about $R/M$, work with $F:=R/M$ abstractly.

Comment: @Via If you don't trust working in $R/M$ abstractly, Martin's proof gives you $\bar{x}\in R/M$ such that $\bar{a}+\bar{x}\bar{b}=\bar{1}$ (overlining means the image of an element in $R/M$). Thus $a+xb=1+y$, for some $y\in M$, but then $a+xb\notin M$, otherwise $1\in M$.

Comment: Yes I got it assuming two cases 'a' equals to 0 and 'a' not equal to 0.Thank you @Martin Brandenburg